# How to get values from Application.properties or yaml file in a non Spring class

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring application, and I am creating an object for a class using a `new` operator. In the class, I am trying to fetch values from my `application.properties`. I annotated the class with `@Service` for which I am creating an object with new operator. It doesn't make any difference.

```java
@Service
public class Myclass {
    @Value("$(myVariable)")
    private String myvariable;
}
```

Class In which i am creating an object of the above class using new operator

```java
public class AnotherNonSpringClass {
    MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
}
```

How do I get values from `application.properties`?

Comment: [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](//stackoverflow.com/q/19896870)

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating object with new keyword then you have to manage the object spring will not maintain the object which was created by new keyword

but still have chance to inject the property by creating object with new keyword simply you need service which gives you property value.

```
public class ValueProvider {
    public String getProperty(String propertyName) throws IOException {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:application.properties")));
        return prop.getProperty(propertyName);
    }
}
```

after this

```
public class AnotherNonSpringClass {
   MyClass myClass = new MyClass(new ValueProvider().getProperty("myvariable"));
}
```

and finally,

```
@Service
public class MyClass
{
    @Value("$(myVariable)")
    private String myvariable;

    public MyClass() {}

    public MyClass(String prop) { 
        this.myVariable = prop; 
    }
}
```